# Composite JSF 2.2 component with validation message not displayed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, composite-component, myfaces

I working on custom JSF 2.2 components with corporate design.
I have a problem with input text.
The problem is that if I use my component and want to specify `<h:message for="id_of_component"/>` its not work. Because the id of component is different.

```
<h:message for="input"/>
<custom:input id="input" required="true"/>
```

If i specify it inside component it works but it's not what I want. It should be flexible in case anyone want to use message on diferent place than I specify in component.

Component definition (with message):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
          xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
          xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

    <!-- INTERFACE -->
    <cc:interface name="input" expert="true">
        <cc:attribute name="id" required="false"/>
        <cc:attribute name="label" />
        <cc:attribute name="value" />
        <cc:attribute name="title" />
        <cc:attribute name="readonly" default="false" type="java.lang.Boolean" />
        <cc:attribute name="required" default="false" type="java.lang.Boolean" />
        <cc:attribute name="rendered" default="true" type="java.lang.Boolean" />
        <cc:attribute name="placeholder" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <cc:clientBehavior name="click" targets=":#{cc.id}" event="click" default="true"/>
        <cc:clientBehavior name="change" targets=":#{cc.id}" event="change" default="true"/>
        <cc:clientBehavior name="blur" targets=":#{cc.id}" event="blur" default="true"/>
        <cc:clientBehavior name="keyup" targets=":#{cc.id}" event="keyup" default="true"/>
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <h:panelGrid rendered="#{cc.attrs.rendered}" columns="2" id="panel" styleClass="customInputWrapper">
            <h:outputLabel title="#{cc.attrs.title}"
                           value="#{cc.attrs.label}#{cc.attrs.required ? ' *' : ''}" for="#{cc.attrs.id}" />
            <h:inputText id="#{cc.attrs.id}" styleClass="customInput" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" p:placeholder="#{cc.attrs.placeholder}" readonly="#{cc.attrs.readonly}" title="#{cc.attrs.title}" required="#{cc.attrs.required}"/>
            <h:message for="#{cc.attrs.id}" />
            <h:outputStylesheet library="custom" name="customComponentsStyle.css"/>

        </h:panelGrid>
    </cc:implementation>
    </html>
```

Do you have any solution how to solve this problem?